# How remove white space between image border radius and it's parent container border radius

Tags: flutter

I'm a beginner with Flutter and after test many solutions, I am blocked.
I want to remove the space between my border container and his child image. Both have border radius.
Below, my code snippet end the image.
Thanks for your precious help.

```
    Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: double.infinity * screenWidthRatio,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      border: Border.all(color: blueColor, width: 3),
                      gradient: const LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.centerRight,
                        end: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        colors: [
                          Colors.black,
                          Colors.black87,
                          Colors.black54,
                          Colors.transparent,
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
                          child: Image.network(
                            'https://img.lemde.fr/2022/02/06/0/0/0/0/580/0/75/0/a8d87fe_5475999-01-06.jpg',
                          ),
                        ),
                        // Future column
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
```

Here the example

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because of `Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 3)` that pushes the image. in my idea if you use `Stack` you can reach to your idea.

```
      Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://img.lemde.fr/2022/02/06/0/0/0/0/580/0/75/0/a8d87fe_5475999-01-06.jpg',
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Future column
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
            height: 100,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 3),
              gradient: const LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerRight,
                end: Alignment.centerLeft,
                colors: [
                  Colors.black,
                  Colors.black87,
                  Colors.black54,
                  Colors.transparent,
                ],
              ),
            ),
      ),
          ],
        )
```

[image]
happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

if you can use your image from image assets then use this code in container decoration

```
  image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("Enter Your Image Path here")),
```

**if you don't want  to use AssetImage then here is the code ---->**

```
 Container(
            height: 100,
            width: Get.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
              gradient: const LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerRight,
                end: Alignment.centerLeft,
                colors: [
                  Colors.black,
                  Colors.black87,
                  Colors.black54,
                  Colors.transparent,
                ],
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius:  BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://img.lemde.fr/2022/02/06/0/0/0/0/580/0/75/0/a8d87fe_5475999-01-06.jpg',
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
                // Future column
              ],
            ),
          )
```

*i have reduced the width of the container in this and use box fit  . if you can use AssetsImage  always  use image in container decoration as i used in above code*